# java class file to jar app

Tags: jar, nokia

i want to know how to make a jar app which will run on java mobile platform using class file of java.
i know basics of java like inheritance,interface,string.....I tried this thing by compiling my java program of simple input/output and then converting it to jar using -jar in cmd.but i dont know why it is not working on mobile showing invalid file.
plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a jar application, starting from a java class,you don't have to use `java -jar filename.jar`, this is only for execution.

Try this: `jar cf your_jar_app.jar your_class_file.class`

`c` option is needed to create file and `f` option is needed because you want an output file.

Then you can execute typing: `java -jar your_jar_app.jar`

Hope this can help you.

For documentation: [Oracle Documentation for creating JAR file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)
If you are using NetBeans IDE, take a look to: [NetBeans Packaging and Deploying Java Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1)